# Cant display a list of all categories under a post_type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, categories

I have been trying to create a page on wordpress that displays all categories with images, title and links of all categories of a particular post_type.

I have added the following code to my functions.php file:

```
function show_categories($excl=''){
   $categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
     if(!empty($categories)){
        $exclude=$excl;
        $exclude = explode(",");
        foreach ($categories as $cat) {
            if(!in_array($cat->cat_ID)) {
            echo '<div class="product-category">';
            // echo '<p>' . $cat->category_description . '</p>';
            echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) . '" />';
            echo '<img src="';
            echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id, 'products') . '" />';
            echo '</a>';
            echo '<h2><a href="' . get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) . '" class="cat-link"';
            echo '/>' . $cat->cat_name . '</a></h2>';
            echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) . '" class="more-info" >Info</a>';
            echo '</div>';
            }
          }

      }
}
```

**Now the problem is:** It only displays the categories of the latest post. If the latest post is included to all categories, all categories will show up, if not it will only show the categories relevant to the latest post.

I call this function on the file archive-products.php like this:

```
<?php show_categories(); ?>
```

Any ideas?

This is the page: http://giannacamilotti.com/products/

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, the code below worked!

```
function show_categories($excl=''){
$args=array(
'post_type' => 'Products'
);
   $categories = get_categories($args);
     if(!empty($categories)){
        $exclude=$excl;
        $exclude = explode(",");
        foreach ($categories as $cat) {
            echo '<div class="product-category ' . $cat->cat_name . ' ">';
            echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) . '" />';
            echo '<img src="';
            echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id, 'products') . '" />';
            echo '</a>';
            echo '<h2><a href="' . get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) . '" class="cat-link"';
            echo '/>' . $cat->cat_name . '</a></h2>';
            echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) . '" class="more-info" >Info</a>';
            echo '</div>';
            }

      }
}
```

Please let me know if anyone has a better and cleaner solution.